# Getting Sandboxed Solution to Work in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a SharePoint 2010 implementation that we are in the process of migrating to SharePoint 2013 On-Line.

Part of the implementation includes a custom Event Receiver that moves documents between identical Document Libraries depending on the status of a boolean field. This functionality uses strictly SharePoint and .Net libraries.

Another part of the same Event Receiver connects to Microsoft CRM and updates a name field. This part uses the microsoft.crm.sdk and microsoft.crm.sdktypeproxy assemblies.

We have not been able to get this solution to work in the SP on-line environment and I suspect it is because of the CRM assemblies. Can anyone tell me if this is or could be the case and also if I remove all of the portions that apply to the CRM (including the references to the CRM assemblies) will that get me further along than I am now?

Comment: Have you thought of porting it to a remote event receiver? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I don't know that a remote event receiver is the direction we want to go in. We're hoping to simplify the solution and get it working as is if at all possible. We have considered re-writing it as a SharePoint app but would prefer not to do that either. Is there a technical reason why this might only work as a remote event receiver?

Comment: Sandboxed solutions are going away at some point the last I knew. So it is either rewrite as an add-in or a RER.

Comment: Thanks Eric . . . I knew about Sandboxed solutions going away . . . I was just hoping to get this up and running faster. I did go through and remove all of the CRM code and references and the WSP deploys okay but it's still not functioning. I am wondering if there is something we need to do to make sure that the event is actually firing or additional config that needs to be done to wire up the handler. Any thoughts?